# XML .NET Library

Tags: .net, xml

Is it any XML .net library like simplexml in PHP?
For example:

```
<root>
 <obj>
  <val>value1</val>
 </obj>
 <obj>
  <val>value1</val>
 </obj>
</root>

objects = .....Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(objects[0].val.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there's the [`XMLDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class>

> Represents an XML document.
>
> **Namespace:**  System.Xml
>   **Assembly:**  System.Xml (in System.Xml.dll)
>
> This class implements the W3C Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1 Core and the Core DOM Level 2. The DOM is an in-memory (cache) tree representation of an XML document and enables the navigation and editing of this document.

Answer (score 0):

[Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is probably pretty close once you get used to the Linq syntax.  Some good samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx#linqoverview_topic7).  Then you can use [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) to get all of the elements below it, or [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) to get a collection of immediate children, etc.  The query syntax is quite nice for filtering out just the stuff you care about though.  For example you can get to all of the elements of type `obj` using:

```
var root = XElemenet.Parse( /* [xml string goes here] */ );

var objects = root.Descendants("obj");
foreach( var o in objects ){
   Console.WriteLine( o.Value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an schema from your xml document and then generate a class from that schema. After that, you can use serialization to read/write xml documents.

More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx

In the "Remarks" section you'll find "xsd to classes" where the XmlSerialization approach is mentioned.